# Convert underscores to spaces in Matlab string?

Tags: string, matlab, replace

So say I have a string with some underscores like hi_there.

Is there a way to auto-convert that string into "hi there"?

(the original string, by the way, is a variable name that I'm converting into a plot title).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surprising that no-one has yet mentioned `strrep`:

```
>> strrep('string_with_underscores', '_', ' ')
ans =
string with underscores
```

which should be the [official way](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) to do a simple string replacements. For such a simple case, `regexprep` is overkill: yes, they are Swiss-knifes that can do everything possible, but they come with a long manual. String indexing shown by AndreasH only works for replacing single characters, it cannot do this:

```
>> s = 'string*-*with*-*funny*-*separators';
>> strrep(s, '*-*', ' ')
ans =
string with funny separators

>> s(s=='*-*') = ' '
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

As a bonus, it also works for cell-arrays with strings:

```
>> strrep({'This_is_a','cell_array_with','strings_with','underscores'},'_',' ')
ans = 
    'This is a'    'cell array with'    'strings with'    'underscores'
```

Comment: `strrep` is also much much faster than `regexprep`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this Matlab code for a string variable 's'

```
s(s=='_') = ' ';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you ever have to do anything more complicated, say doing a replacement of multiple variable length strings,

`s(s == '_') = ' '` will be a huge pain. If your replacement needs ever get more complicated consider using `regexprep`:

```
>> regexprep({'hi_there', 'hey_there'}, '_', ' ')
ans = 
    'hi there'    'hey there'
```

That being said, in your case @AndreasH.'s solution is the most appropriate and `regexprep` is overkill.

A more interesting question is why you are passing variables around as strings?

Answer (score 2):

regexprep() may be what you're looking for and is a handy function in general.

```
regexprep('hi_there','_',' ')
```

Will take the first argument string, and replace instances of the second argument with the third.  In this case it replaces all underscores with a space.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab strings are vectors, so performing simple string manipulations can be achieved using standard operators e.g. replacing _ with  whitespace.

```
text = 'variable_name';
text(text=='_') = ' '; //replace all occurrences of underscore with whitespace
=> text = variable name
```

Comment: This does not work in Matlab (maybe Octave) because of the double quotes

Comment: My bad. Yea I use Octave :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this was already answered, however, in my case I was looking for a way to correct plot titles so that I could include a filename (which could have underscores).  So, I wanted to print them with the underscores NOT displaying with as subscripts.  So, using this great info above, and rather than a space, I escaped the subscript in the substitution.

```
For example:
% Have the user select a file:
[infile inpath]=uigetfile('*.txt','Get some text file');

figure
% this is a problem for filenames with underscores
title(infile)

% this correctly displays filenames with underscores 
title(strrep(infile,'_','\_'))
```

Comment: Hello, please make sure answers to questions are actually answering the question asked.